# Nearest neighbor information for recommendation engines

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, recommender-system

My friend and I are working on a project on distributed datastructures. We were wondering how much is nearest neighbor information used in modern recommendation systems and whether it would be worthwhile to work on a distributed datastructure (say a kd-tree) for that purpose.

Thanks

Comment: Your question seems to require a lengthy essay style response.  Do you think you could rephrase this into a few more focal questions?